# Get objects from objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, many-to-many

i'm currently working on a web app and I've some trouble to do a query

I've User and Building model.

Each building has many users and some users can manage building.

Currently I would like to do something like :

```rb
current_user.buildings.users
```

to get all users of managed building.

I tried with array and hash but the fact is that I need to still be able to do some filter and search on it :

```rb
@users = User.search(params[:search], params[:building], params[:company]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 50, :page => params[:page])
```

The solutions should like :

```rb
current_user.buildings.users.search(params[:search], params[:building], params[:company]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 50, :page => params[:page])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is?  Have you implemented a `search` class method on `User`?

Comment: Could you please include your models and their associations, e.g. `class User; has_many ...; end` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer using relationship between models, didn't think that RoR would be so powerful ^^